# Are wifi enabled SDCARDs a viable option for my 3d printer?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, sd-card

For a PC I have a HP Envy running Windows 7.   It is attached via usb cable to my Flashforge Creator Dual 3d printer.  Conventional Internet Wisdom suggests that it is better to store your model on an SDCARD and insert that into the printer, so that the stream of commands going to the printer stays at a steady rate.   This should result in a better print.

Having become aware of wifi enableds sdcards, my question boils down to

"If it get one, and plug it into the printer, will i be able to, in effect, mount it as a external hard drive on my pc?"

I am doing something similar with with a MYBOOKLIVE, which is simply some network attached storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in most cases the WiFi SD is only accessible via a browser to download **from** the card, not to it. The use case is you take pictures with your camera and download them via a browser or the utility the card manufacturer provides.

[See this](https://ultimaker.com/en/community/16611-wirelessly-transfer-files-to-printer-with-wifi-sd-card)